# xcode post to php with textfields

Tags: php, ios, mysql, xcode

I am trying to use Xcode textfields to post onto my mysql server. The issue is that i don't get errors in Xcode or php but the post never gets inserted into my mysql table. I know the url is right as well as the username and password and dbname etc. Here is my code when the submit button is pressed in Xcode:

```
NSString * post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"message=test&name=%@", name.text];
NSData * postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];

NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/Upload.php"]]]
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection * conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[conn start];

if (conn) NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
```

my php looks like this:

```
<?php
/*
Johnny
JUL, 2011
*/
    $DB_HostName = "localhost";
    $DB_Name = "test";
    $DB_User = "root";
    $DB_Pass = "root";
    $DB_Table = "test";

    $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db($DB_Name) or die(mysql_error()); 

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO Locations('name','message') VALUES('$name','$message')";

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error("error"));

    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: it's not a question. In client u send data in body with POST method, and server catch this data need to be int $_POST

Comment: I changed it to post and it still didn't work. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: What "doesn't work?" Please be specific with your questions. We cannot help you if you cannot help us help you.

Comment: Sorry!!I revised it please look again!

Comment: try format body data with [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

Comment: I tried that...didnt upload to mysql